# Can't prevent echo line from displaying when batch file run

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I've got a large batch file and I'm sending some commands to a txt file and I've separated the sections with a space using

```
echo && echo(  >> file.txt
```

When I run it, it does create the spaces perfectly but in the command window I get this

```
ECHO is off.
```

How can I prevent this from showing. I've searched on this site but whatever I try does not seem to work.

Here is more detail -

```
@echo off
echo SetMTMode^(2^) >> file.txt
echo echo(  >> file.txt
```

When I run this the first line is echoed into the txt file, it's a command for further processing later. The second echo is not blanked it shows on screen but it does echo (copy) to the txt file. It shows -

```
ECHO is off.
```

How to turn that statement off?

Comment: What is the exact text are you trying to put in the file? `echo` by itself will display the status of echo (either on or off), which is exactly what the `echo` before the `&&` is doing.

Comment: If you want to output the conditional execution `&&` signs literal you have to escape them with a caret `^&^&`. Without escaping the first echo is executed (without error) and the second one is redirected to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` executes the second command only if the first is successful.

In this case, the first command will always succeed, so there is no requirement for `&&` - `&` will do the same thing (there seems to be a plague of `&&` at present on SO)

So - you are running two separate commands. The first is `echo` and the second `echo(  >> file.txt`

Since only the second command is redirected, its output will appear on the file. The first is not redirected so its output will appear on the console.

`echo` with no argument will report the current `echo` status, which is what you are seeing. Since you don't say what you do want to see, merely that you don't want to see the echo status, we're guessing.

If you want to see *nothing at all* on the console, then omit the first `echo`.

If you want to see a blank line, then use one of the standard `show a blank line` methods - `echo.` and `echo(` being favourites.

Your second command - well, again you don't say what you actually want on the file, but it's placing a line containing two spaces on the file.

`echo` followed by no text will report the `echo` status.
`echo(` or `echo.` followed by no text will provide a newline (CR LF)
`echo(` or `echo.` followed by spaces will insert those spaces before a newline (CR LF)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I had @echo off at the top of the batch file already. I want the batch file to echo a blank line into the txt file and when it does this I don't want it to show in the command window, I want blank, nothing.

Comment: `@echo off` simply turns off the instruction-reporting. It has no effect on how `echo` works beyond that, other than `echo` alone will say `echo is OFF` in place of `echo is ON`. As I said, If you want to see nothing at all on the console, then omit the first `echo` and implicitly, the `&`(s) since it/they then have no purpose.

Comment: I expanded my comment in the first post. I can't omit the first echo because that copies my statement into the txt file. Oh maybe your right, delete the first echo. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a blank line using **echo**, simply do:

```
echo. >>file.txt
```

The dot has to follow the echo with no space.